# Folium Layer Control : how to properly control the display (fontsize, space,...)?

Tags: format, folium

As a Folium novice, I have recently embarked on the creation of a map with many layers organized in SubGroup thanks to `folium.plugins.FeatureGroupSubGroup(FeatureGroup,"nameOfMyLayerDisplayed").add_child(MyLayer).add_to(myMap)`.
Those layers are displayed on my map thanks to `folium.LayerControl().add_to(myMap)`.

Wishing to refine the rendering of this layer control, **I would like to play with the font size and the spacing between the layers displayed in the layer control**.

I have seen that a complete redefinition of the Layer Control is possible : [Leaflet custom layer control](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50682634/12463368) but seems quite a though work for what I want to achieve.

My problem comes probably from a lack of knowledge about Leaflet's and HTML's intersections with folium, could you maybe help me ?

Thank you in advance.